# Export socket.io from server.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

My folder structure is like so:

```
server
 - routes
 -- api
 --- otherfile.js
server.js
```

I'm running socket.io from my server.js file and everything works fine like this:

```
// Set up server
const express = require('express');
const axios = require("axios");
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(port);

require('./routes')(app);

// Set up socket.io
var io = require("socket.io")(server);

// Method for socket.io
const getApiAndEmit = async socket => {
  try {
    // get data from API
    const res = await axios.get("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/XXXX/37.8267,-122.4233");
    // emit event from socket
    socket.emit("FromAPI", res.data.currently.temperature);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error ${error.code}`);
  }
}

// Set up interval for socket
let interval;

// Logic for socket
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('New client connected');
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval); // clear interval on subsequent connections
  }
  interval = setInterval(() => getApiAndEmit(socket), 10000);
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log("client disconnected");
  })
})
```

Now I need to export io so I can use it in another file and I've tried this:

Added to the bottom of server.js

```
module.exports = io
OR
module.exports = { io: io }
```

Otherfile.js (import to /routes/api/otherfile.js)

```
let socket = require('../../server'); //the module is found OK

socket.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log('client connected');
})
```

I'm getting socket.on is not a function error.

Another Approach Failing
Meanwhile I have tried a different approach and it works with a new file that is in the same directory as the server.js file but when I try to import the code to /routes/api/otherfile.js I get cannot read property on of null

Created io.js (in same directory as server.js)

```
var sio = require('socket.io');
var io = null;

exports.io = function () {
  return io;
};

exports.initialize = function (server) {
  return io = sio(server);
};
```

Test.js (same directory as server.js and works as expected)

```
require('./io').io().on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('testing')
})
```

Otherfile.js (/routes/api/otherfile.js and throws cannot read property 'on' of null)

```
require('../../io').io().on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('testing')
})
```

Additionally,

I can console log the require statements from both test.js and otherfile.js and they both return the same.

```
Test.js Log
console.log(require('./io'));  //{ io: [Function], initialize: [Function] }

Otherfile.js Log
console.log(require('../../io')); //{ io: [Function], initialize: [Function] }
```

Comment: the "working" code's, your exporting `io` not `socket` so `let socket = require('../../server');` wont work as expected

Comment: @LawrenceCherone In the second example where I got it working for test.js I changed the code in otherfile.js to ```require('../../io').io().on('connection', socket =>```

Comment: Im convinced it has something to do with the fact that I'm trying to import into /routes/api/otherfile.js but I don't understand why or how to fix it.

Comment: You cant do `socket.on("connection",` in multiple places, and `socket` witin the callback is the single client, you cant export it, if you want to abstract out the code, inject own callbacks ot add an event bus etc.